# Replace characters in the middle of a string

Tags: r, replace, radix

I have the following df

```
df <- data.frame(name.name1 = c(1, 1, 1),
                 name.name2 = c(2, 2, 2),
                 name.name3 = c(3, 3, 3))
```

I'm trying to substitute `.` by space. When I do

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("^.$", " ", colnames(df))
```

What's happening here and how can I proceed?

Comment: You don't need the anchors: `gsub("\\.", " ", colnames(df))`

Comment: a dot is a special character. you have to preceede it with \\ like this `colnames(df) <- gsub("\\.", " ", colnames(df))`

Comment: Ah...I see. Basically all special characters need \\ then?

Comment: Yes, exactly, Or add them between brackets`[]`

Comment: Yes, if you want the literal character for those that are special, you either need to escape it with the double-backslash, or you can use `fixed=TRUE` if you want no regex evaluation in the "pattern" (which is, at that point, just a fixed string).

Comment: yes - there may be some exceptions but in general all special characters do

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks, my boys. I'll accept @cgvoller answer since it's out there so ppl can find the fix in the future without going to the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the dot with double back slash like so

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("\\.", " ", colnames(df))
```

Output:

```
"name name1" "name name2" "name name3"
```

Answer (score 3):

Go back one step and avoid them in the first place, using *check.names* argument:

```
#when creating a dataframe
data.frame("name name1" = c(1, 1, 1),
           "name name2" = c(2, 2, 2),
           "name name3"= c(3, 3, 3), check.names = FALSE)
#   name name1 name name2 name name3
# 1          1          2          3
# 2          1          2          3
# 3          1          2          3

#when importing data from file
read.table("myFile.txt", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```